# Limit of a sequence true or false statement

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose $S(0)=2$, and $$S(n+1)=\dfrac{(S(n))²+2}{2S(n)}.$$ Then $\lim_{n\to\infty} S(n)= \sqrt2$.

So I worked some of the terms out and I get $S(1)=\frac{3}{2}$, $S(2)= \frac{17}{12}$,...

I did the limit of $(x^2+2)/(2x)=∞$ so the statement is false or what am I missing here?

I think $\sqrt{2}$ is the infimum.

Comment: **If** you know (or proved) the limit exits, call it $\;\alpha\;$ , then doing arithmetic of limits you get:$$\alpha=\frac{\alpha^2+2}{2\alpha}\implies \alpha^2=2\iff\alpha=\pm\sqrt 2$$ and checking a little your sequence one of these two possibilities falls.

Comment: Can you show the convergence?

Comment: That's is Newton-Rapson for $\large x^{2} - 2 = 0$.

Comment: by definition I'd say there is an epsilon>0 and M>0 s.t. n>M then the distance between the sequence and and the limit is less than epsilon. We assume that the sequence converges so there is a limit  so we plug in L and solve. Is this correct?

Comment: If you need to assume that the sequence converges, you did not solve the exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***If*** you can show that the sequence converges at all, then letting $L$ be the limit, we take the limit as $n\to\infty$ on both sides of the recurrence $$s_{n+1}=\frac{s_n^2+2}{2s_n},$$ to obtain $$L=\frac{L^2+2}{2L}.$$ Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
S(n+1)-\sqrt2=\frac{(S(n)-\sqrt2)^2}{2S(n)},
$$
hence $S(n)\geqslant\sqrt2$ for every $n$ and
$$
S(n+1)-\sqrt2=\frac{S(n)-\sqrt2}{2S(n)}(S(n)-\sqrt2)\leqslant\frac12(S(n)-\sqrt2).
$$
Thus, for every $n$,
$$
\sqrt2\leqslant S(n)\leqslant\sqrt2+\frac1{2^n}(S(0)-\sqrt2).
$$

Comment: @CameronBuie Thanks (and the downvote completes nicely the picture, I must say...).